# How to add a watermark as a loop using ffmpeg sliding overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark, overlay

I'm using ffmpeg overlay to add a watermark (.PNG ) to a video clip. This watermark should slide from top to bottom of the video repeatedly as a loop, through out the length of the video.  I could configure to add the watermark to slide from top to bottom.

My Problem: It slides only once. It does not start over as a loop.

My code:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y='if(gte(t,0), -H+(t)*20, NAN)':shortest=1" output.mkv
```

Could you please help me to rectify this issue?

Thank you

Anoma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -loop 1 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y='if(gte(t,0), ((H+h)\/5)\*mod(t\,5)-h, NAN)':shortest=1" \
output.mkv
```

5 seconds is the period of the above expression. Change both `5`s to alter the period.

Unless you're working with files with negative timestamps such as segmented or files split using ffmpeg `-ss` in `copy` mode, you can skip the `gte` function.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -loop 1 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y='((H+h)\/5)\*mod(t\,5)-h':shortest=1" \
output.mkv
```

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Could you please tell me how should I change your code to move the watermark from BOTTOM to TOP ? Thank you very much.

Comment: I changed the code and it works fine. > ffmpeg -i input.mkv -loop 1 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y='if(gte(t,0), ((-H-h)\/20)\*mod(t\,20)+H, NAN)':shortest=1" output.mkv

Comment: I can't seem to understand what those 5s do. Upon changing they alter the speed of the overlay, but how to set the period and the speed of the overlay?

Comment: @r.mirzojonov The overlay animation is the motion of the watermark from the top of the frame to the bottom, so the period and speed are related.  If the period is X seconds, then the overlay anim has to be complete within X seconds, so smaller the period, the faster the motion has to be.

Comment: Now, if you want a pause between loops, change to `((H+h)\/5)\*mod(t\,10)-h` where the overlay anim will take 5 secs and a new loop will start every 10 secs.

Comment: @Gyan Thank you, it worked!

Comment: @Gyan since we are at it, could you tell how to make it move from right to left?

Comment: `x='W-((W+w)\/5)\*mod(t\,10)'`

Comment: @Gyan you are the best!