# FFMPEG overlay move to to above every 5s

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the ffmpeg overlay to add a watermark (.MOV) and text to a video clip. This watermark must move to top and above every 5 seconds along the length of the video.

My problem: can't move above

My Code

```
ffmpeg -i final.mp4 -i "logo.mov" -filter_complex "[1:v:0]scale=100:-1[inner];[0:v:0][inner]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,5)+between(t,6,10)',drawtext=fontfile=C:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=2:x=5:y=50:text=@(username):enable='between(t,0,5)+between(t,6,10)'[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a? TOP.mp4
```

Could you please help me to rectify this issue?

Thank you

NANO

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1049977

Comment: thanks @Gyan , but not sliding movement from top to above . I mean [Like This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DkLdWUpsUCcao33xmIaDoEZ6qqSmSHmH/view) , if you are willing to open it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58706910

Comment: cool sir @Gyan   I learned once what you share, but it moves clockwise. I'm sorry before. If you wish, how do you make the logo and text overlay start from the top left every 5 seconds move to the bottom right. Thank you, sir